# Searching for an adapted cli browser

Tags: javascript, browser, command-line-interface, spotify

I'm currently stuck on a big problem, I'm searching for a CLI browser with audio and javascript support.

My project is to play a playlist on raspberry pi from Spotify, and all this thing **headlessly**.

So I have a python script to control what playlist I want to hear, play and pause the playback

I also have the web playback SDK of Spotify (this little tutorial here: https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-playback-sdk/quick-start/)
And with the script, I open this web page and play the music on

The problem now is that I need to make it without having to open those Firefox, Chrome etc., because I'm making it totally headless.

I've tried to search for cli web browser that could handle javascript but no really good result (w3m, phantomJS, links, elinks, edbrowser ...)

But the real question is: ***Could a text-based web browser support audio?***

If there's a way to use the web page in a web browser headlessly that's good, otherwise I might have to think another way to use the web playback without having to open the page in a browser.

Thanks, cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are searching is simply a JavaScript runtime without the need of a browser.

If so, you can simply use [`Node.js`](https://nodejs.org/en/)

> Node.js® is a JavaScript runtime built on Chrome's V8 JavaScript
>   engine. Node.js uses an event-driven, non-blocking I/O model that
>   makes it lightweight and efficient. Node.js' package ecosystem, npm,
>   is the largest ecosystem of open source libraries in the world.

You can use Node.js to run JavScript code almost the same way as in the browser. You can perfectly run audio or record audio ([node-aplay](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-aplay)) on a Raspberry Pi with it. Here you just need to install ALSA which can be used for audio playback.

So my answer is: You do not need a web based app, you don´t need a web browser. Just node, ALSA and node-aplay and a simple script that will do that.

Comment: Oh ok ! I've heard of node.js but I'm uncertain about his compatibility with python, can I include a node.js script into a python script ? Or do I have to run the node.js script + the python script (to control spotify) ?

Comment: if you use python, why you dont just play your sound using python? https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/7088/playing-audio-files-with-python. You then do not need a web sdk from spotify, you could use something that already works with raspberry without javascript. https://dtcooper.github.io/raspotify/

Comment: The reason why I need the web SDK is because I've already tried raspotify and other API that provide a Spotify Connect device to play on. But in the case of raspotify, I had an issue where all the people on my network were able to select the device in their spotify instance. Also I had to select the RPI device once before being able to detect it via the python script

Comment: okay, I cannot help with that, but if you want to call node from python, you surely can. I think something like `subprocess.call(["node", "myscript.js"])`. I don´t do python, so I´m just guessing the syntax.